# Importing numpy from a prebuilt binary zip

Tags: python, numpy, zip, python-import

I installed numpy on my mac using `pip install numpy`
After this I took the installed package from `site-packages` and created a zip archive called `numpy.zip`
I try to import numpy using the zip as follows:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0,'numpy.zip')
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
  File "numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

I checked the `numpy/core/` directory and I see a `multiarray.so` file present in it.

This same technique has worked for other packages but somehow is failing for numpy. **I also want to point out that importing the unzipped numpy module is succeeding.**

Comment: Numpy has C extensions that are compiled and give it its speed.  It is not satisfactory to simply copy site-packages.

Comment: @StephenRauch I need to have a prebuilt numpy to deploy to a production server (where I can't install stuff). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [Pyinstaller?](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Comment: @StephenRauch since there are C extensions, it can't be cross-platform right?

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this problem and PyInstaller might be a way to solve this, if you have a program at hand that will use the zipped dependencies.

The main problem at hand is that the zip contains shared libraries (*.so files), which are not in any of the places where your system looks for shared libraries. Even if you would specify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to zip file>/numpy.zip`, the system would still not find the shared libraries. For that to happen you have to unpack the zip file, then you can specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH to where the zip was unpacked. If that happens to be your current working directory, then you will most likely not have to add your current working directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH as the system most likely search the current working directory anyway.

In my case it's trickier as I need the dependencies to be included in a Spark/Zeppelin setup where I have no main-program which PyInstaller could analyze at hand. I cannot include any main program as that's what the Zeppelin notebook server is for.

My case can be reproduced as follows, using numpy as an example. Consider numpy.dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim as base

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y \
    zip \
    python3 \
    python3-pip

# Make sure we have the latest tools
RUN pip3 install -U pip
RUN pip3 install -U wheel setuptools

FROM base as pkgbuilder

RUN mkdir pkg pkg1
WORKDIR /pkg
RUN pip3 install numpy -t .
RUN zip -r9 /pkg.zip * -x *.pyc

FROM base

RUN mkdir test
COPY --from=pkgbuilder /pkg.zip /test/
```

Build it as such: `docker build -f numpy.dockerfile -t numpy .`. Now you have an image tagged numpy:latest. Now we use that image, `docker run -it -e PYTHONPATH=/test/pkg.zip numpy python3 -c 'import numpy'`.

As output I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                               
  File "/test/pkg.zip/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/test/pkg.zip/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/test/pkg.zip/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/test/pkg.zip/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
  File "/test/pkg.zip/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "/usr/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

As the system will not look into zip files for shared libraries, then this problem cannot be solved in my case.